# How to setup ViewController in Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift-playground

In swift playgrounds how do you setup a viewcontroller and use it? I've done it with a UIView before but the UI gets cut when in a difference orientation so I want to try use a viewcontroller. 
I've got `let view = UIViewController()` but after that how do I set it up to add a background and stuff on it?

Answer (score 40):

To create a view controller in a Swift playground you need this code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // do setup here
    }        
}

let viewController = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Sorry thought the answer disappearing was an error, I'll edit the answer @EricAya

Comment: This line `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` is only necessary if you're running asynchronous code.

Answer (score 4):

Example of UIViewController in Playground with multiple Subviews and Auto layout.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var yellowView: UIView!
    var redView: UIView!

    override func loadView() {

        // UI

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        yellowView = UIView()
        yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(yellowView)

        redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(redView)

        // Layout
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            yellowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            yellowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            yellowView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            yellowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),

            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant: -20),
            redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
            ])

        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

[image]