# How can I set a VC as Liveview in Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift-playground

I'm currently working on a small Playgrounds project (for macOS) and I'm trying to set my own View Controller as the Live View. The following line doesn't work.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

When running this, I get the following error.

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

I get the same error, when using this:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController(nibName: NSNib.Name("MyView"), bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose File > New > Playground and start with the MacOS Playground template called Single View. This will give you a view in a nib.

Now modify the code in the playground as follows:

```
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : NSViewController {}

let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
var topLevelObjects : NSArray?

Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibFile, owner:nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
let views = (topLevelObjects as! Array<Any>).filter { $0 is NSView }

let vc = ViewController()
vc.view = views[0] as! NSView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Run the playground and look in the Assistant Editor pane. You will see this:

[image]

---

**EDIT** It occurs to me that a more pleasant way to write this (placing the decision as to where to get its view in the hands of the view controller itself) would be as follows:

```
class ViewController : NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
        var topLevelObjects : NSArray?
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
            nibFile, owner:nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
        let views = (topLevelObjects as! Array<Any>).filter { $0 is NSView }
        self.view = views[0] as! NSView
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more properly object-oriented.

Comment: This is even better. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from because your `ViewController()` does not have any views. Here the link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/loadView).

> If you pass in a nil for nibNameOrNil then nibName will return nil and
>   loadView will throw an exception; in this case you must invoke
>   setView: before view is invoked, or override loadView.

One possible fix:

```
let myVC = NSViewController()
myVC.view = NSView()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myVC
```

In the second case have you set the file's owner of your NIB to your current view controller as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434481-init#discussion) said?

> The specified nib file should typically have the class of the file's
>   owner set to NSViewController, or a custom subclass, with the view
>   outlet connected to a view.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to include the following:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I am attaching the link to the similar question: [How to setup ViewController in Playgrounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160615/how-to-setup-viewcontroller-in-playgrounds)
Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still get the same error. :/